# how to iterate inside a simple_fields_for?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I need to iterate inside the simple_fields_for block to assign a number [0 to 6] to the :day field.

Controller

```
7.times { @doctor.schedules.build }
```

View

```
<tr>
    <% @i = 0 %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :schedules do |builder| %>
    <td>
    <%= builder.input :day, value: @y, wrapper: :check  %>
    <%= builder.input :is_available, as: :boolean, label: false, wrapper: :check %>
    <% @i += 1 %>
    </td>
<% end %>
</tr>
```

obviously this will start from 1 until 7, how can I make it iterate from 0 to 6?

Comment: Assuming @y was supposed to be @i, this seems like it should loop from 0 to 6 as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like mentioned it is possible in Rails 4 after the merge https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5746.
In Rails 4 you can use `.index` on the 'builder':

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :schedules do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.input :day, value: builder.index+1 %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 13):

JFYI, you'll be able to get current index in Rails 4. See [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5746) merged pull request

For now you can use something like this:

```
<% @doctor.schedules.each_with_index do |schedule, index| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :schedules, schedule do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input :day, value: index %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```